# Caliburn issues - RescueAttribute not working

Tags: caliburn

I have some issues with getting the RescueAttribute in Caliburn 1.1.0 to work. Basically I intend to put a general catch-all exception handler in every view model, but I it seems like the method never gets called.

[PerRequest("ConfigurationGroupViewModel")]
    [Rescue("GeneralRescue")]
  public class ConfigurationGroupViewModel : Presenter
{

................

public void GeneralRescue(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

}

I have followed exactly what was specified in the Caliburn documentation, and I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366817/caliburn-exception-handling-and-rescue) earlier that mentioned something about IConventionManager but my concern is that even by putting the rescue method directly on the ViewModel class itself the rescue method never gets called. Can anyone assist me in this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please provide some other details?

- Are you invoking action with messaging infrastructure or manually? (Rescue only works in the first case)
- Are you calling a regular action or a coroutine (IEnumerable)?

Comment: I am invoking the action in the View via cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action SomeActionNameOnVM]", where in the SomeActionNameOnVM method, an exception was thrown somewhere (e.g. throw new Exception()). I was expecting the Rescue method (located on the VM itself) to be called when this happens. I believe that its a regular action (it just has the signature public void SomeActionNameOnVM()).

Comment: I cannot figure out why it's not working. I suggest you to check the  sample in the source code of 1.1 (/tags/Release 1.1). If you still have problems getting it to work and you can build a small repro of the issue, I'll certainly have a look at it.

Comment: I think i figured out the problem. What happened was that I was testing this functionality using Visual studio debug, and I was frustrated that my rescue method was never called, despite me throwing exceptions explicitly (i put a breakpoint on the rescue method). It appears that the method will only get called when I am not running it in debug mode (I tried to run the .exe file afterwards and my method got called). Is this intended, or is this a defect with Caliburn itself?

Comment: Sorry for the *very* late reply. As far I know, there should not be differences in rescue behavior when running with or without debugger.
Do you have a chance of building a small repro?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue with the latest version (1.1.0), hence this question is no longer valid.