# Global handling exception in WPF app with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, exception, caliburn.micro

Hi I try implement solution from this site im my WPF app for global exception handling.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90866/Unhandled-Exception-Handler-For-WPF-Applications.aspx

I use Caliburn Micro as MVVM framework. Service I have in external assembly and it is injected in view model class with MEF.

Here is my implementation for global exception handling in WPF app.

App.xaml

```
         DispatcherUnhandledException="Application_DispatcherUnhandledException"
         Startup="Application_Startup"
```

App class:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private IMessageBox _msgBox = new MessageBoxes.MessageBoxes();

    public bool DoHandle { get; set; }

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    }

    private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender,
                           System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DoHandle)
        {
            _msgBox.ShowException(e.Exception);
             e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            _msgBox.ShowException(e.Exception);
            e.Handled = false;
        }
    }


    void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        var ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
        _msgBox.ShowException(ex);
    }


}
```

Service method from external assembly:

```
    public void ServiceLogOn()
    {
        try
        {

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

This service method is call in view model class for example on button click event:

```
    [Export(typeof(ILogOnViewModel))]
    public class LogOnViewModel : Screen, ILogOnViewModel
    {
        public void LogOn()
        {
            _service.ServiceLogOn();
        }
    }
```

1. I run WPF app in Visual Studio and produce exception with message "Bad credentials" in ServiceLogOn method.

   I expect that I see the message box with the exception.

   But Visual Studio stop debuging app and show exception in service method in service project.
2. So I try run WPF from exe file and produce same exception in ServiceLogOn method.

   I get this error:

   Exception has been throw by target of an invocation.

Any exception from view model class is not handled in methods:

- Application_DispatcherUnhandledException
- or CurrentDomain_UnhandledException.

in App class.

What I do bad?

**EDITED with Simon Fox’s answer.**

I try implement in MEF bootstraper advice of Simon Fox’s, but I still something do wrong.
I move handle logic for exception to OnUnhandledException method in bootstraper class.

Here is my code from bootstraper class:

```
 public class MefBootStrapper : Bootstrapper<IShellViewModel>
    { 
//...
    private IMessageBox _msgBox = new MessageBoxes.MessageBoxes();

    public bool DoHandle { get; set; }

    protected override void OnUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DoHandle)
        {
            _msgBox.ShowException(e.Exception);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            _msgBox.ShowException(e.Exception);
            e.Handled = false;
        }

    }
//...
    }
```

I bind some method from view model on button and throw new exception. Something like this:

```
public void LogOn()
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Bad argument");
}
```

But result is sam, I test app out of Visual Studio and get this exception.

Exception has been throw by target of an invocation.

Comment: Does the Exception have an InnerException, if so what is it? Can you post the StackTrace contained in the exception?

Comment: Hi Simon, Inner exception is null, if I check in Visual Studio, the code in method OnUnhandledException is note executed.

Comment: Simon I make simple sample, if  you want you can try ut. Here is it:http://cid-042424ddb4d5fcbf.office.live.com/self.aspx/MSDN/MVVM%5E_and%5E_global%5E_exceptions%5E_handling.7z

Comment: the sample you provided works fine for me. If you run the sample from visual studio without debugging (Ctrl+F5) you should get the desired result. The other exception is only displayed when the debugger is attached and if you continue execution you will eventually get to the `OnUnhandledException override`

Comment: Thank, Simon, I have problem with Visual Studio :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Caliburn.Micro has built in support for hooking unhandled exceptions. The Bootstrapper class (which every Caliburn project requires) sets this up for you and provides the `virtual` `OnUnhandledException` method.

In your custom `BootStrapper` you must `override` `OnUnhandledException` to perform any custom actions for unhandled exceptions in your app. Note that you will most likely have to marshal actions such as displaying a message box to the UI thread (Caliburn enables this easily via `Execute.OnUIThread`).

You may also have an issue in the way your service moves exceptions to the client, but without any details of how the service is implemented/hosted/etc I cannot help. Are you using WCF to do SOAP? Are you using [FaultContracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733841.aspx)?

Comment: Hi Simon, I am  not using SOAP or REST Web Services, it is only HTTP POST/GET communication, no SOAP /JSON. I edited my question, see it.

Comment: This answer is right. However it didn't work for me since the exception wasn't thrown from the UI thread. I was using `Task`s so I derived from this answer suggesting the use of [Task.ContinueWith](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7297904/448232)