# WP7 and Exceptions Management, Logging and Validation

Tags: windows-phone-7, prism, enterprise-library

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Our team has been spoiled by MS P&P Enterprise Library/Unity as we have made great use of the DI, Exceptions Management, Validation and Logging Capabilities. Traditionally, our front ends have been forms based (Windows Forms, ASP.NET, etc).

As we approach WP7 development, and understanding it is a new platform with much less resources, we are looking to leverage existing frameworks, open source, etc that may exist that deals with these issues on the WP7 client (excepting copy left licensed code).

We are definitely going to implement Prism on WP7, and have started our initial research into the Prism framework capabilities in these areas. It's a great framework, and our initial assessment is that is for legitimate reasons it is more focused on the composite architecture, and we need to use Prism as the architecture to do a little bit more implementation on our own of cross cutting exceptions management, etc capabilities building on the baseline that Prism provides.

Just wanted to confirm, as we have not been able to identify any, that there are no open source or other frameworks out there for WP7 with the Enterprise Library coverage on exceptions management, validation and logging?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WP7Contrib](http://wp7contrib.codeplex.com/) has lots of support for logging, DI and (much) more.

Comment: Looks very helpful. Plus it lead to series of other helpful links. Like I said, we were spoiled by the Enterprise Library breadth of capabilities. The salad days are over :).

Answer (score 0):

well you could use Caliburn Micro

[Global handling exception in WPF app with Caliburn.Micro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886876/global-handling-exception-in-wpf-app-with-caliburn-micro)

not sure if this goes down with the PRISM well though

22 sept 2011

there is siverlight integration on the enterprise library http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices

Comment: thank u for the heads up. Must improve my Google skills in order to pick these items up. :) The View Model centric approach, versus the more View approach of Prism, is very interesting. Intellectually appealing.