# How to handle exceptions in async code with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, caliburn.micro

I have a Button in my View `<Button Content="Search" cal:Message.Attach="SearchAsync"/>` which calls a function, which raises an exception. I am trying to catch this exception in my Bootstrapper class with

```
protected override void OnUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    e.Exception.Log();
}
```

- If the function looks like this: `public async Task SearchAsync()` the error is just swallowed and the OnUnhandledException is never reached,
- if the function looks like this: `public async void SearchAsync()` it throws an exception but the debugger stops and waits for me to press continue in the void function and I need to create a void function for every Task function and
- if I use an [AsyncReactiveCommand](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI) it is able to catch the exception in OnUnhandledException but using a command results again in extra code (`SearchCommand = new AsyncReactiveCommand().WithSubscribe(async () => await SearchAsync());`).

As far as I have understood async void should be used for actions because they are event handlers [(source)](https://caraulean.com/2013/using-caliburn-micro-with-async-await/).

Solutions I have come up with are: Either use a Command or wrap the Task function in a try/catch, neither of which I am really satisfied with.

What is the right way to work with async and await in Caliburn.Micro and still use the cal:Message.Attach="xyz" syntax?

Preferably I would like to use the async Task Syntax without anything else because it provides the best test-ability and needs the least amount of code.

Comment: _It throws an unhandled exception and the UI crashes._ Are you sure it doesn't just break, which is standard behavior if you have a debugger attached, ref [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886876/global-handling-exception-in-wpf-app-with-caliburn-micro#comment5666746_4886876) comment. Continuing execution (pressing F5) should get you through.

Comment: You are right, I overlooked that I can continue but this still doesn't feel right to me.
I edited the question.

Comment: That's probably because it's not meant to _feel right_. Exceptions are for _exceptional_ circumstances, they shouldn't be used for regular program flow.

Comment: You are right but I would still like to catch every exception at some point in the most convenient way. With other words I would like to use async Task and not write wrapper methods for my UI called functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the right way to work with async and await in Caliburn.Micro and still use the cal:Message.Attach="xyz" syntax?

You should catch the exception in `xyz`:

```
public async Task xyz()
{
    try
    {
        //...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //handle...
    }
}
```

If you want to handle it globally in the `OnUnhandledException` of the bootstrapper, you should change the return type from `Task` to `void`. Methods returning `Task` are treated as coroutines.

Comment: Is there a way to catch every exception thrown by Tasks handled in coroutines?